# awk separator escaping |||

Tags: awk, escaping

I have a file in the following format

```
field1 ||| field2 ||| field3
```

I wonder how it's possible to parse it with awk

The following version don't work

```
awk -F"|||" '{print $2}'

awk -F"\|\|\|" '{print $2}'

awk -F" ||| " '{print $2}'
```

What's the right version? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is (using either `bash` or `tcsh` on MacOSX)

```
> echo "field1 ||| field2 ||| field3" > input.txt
> awk -F" \\\|\\\|\\\| " '{print $2}' input.txt
field2
```

Explanation: To paraphrase http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_23.html, since \ is the escape character of the shell, awk sees `-F" \|\|\| "`. Then awk processes the `-F" \|\|\| "` for escape characters, finally yielding `" ||| "` to be used for the field separator.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
awk -F" [|][|][|] " '{print $2}'


echo "field1 ||| field2 ||| field3" | awk -F" [|][|][|] " '{print $2}'
field2
```

As Martin posted, this should work with most `awk`

```
awk -F" [|]{3} " '{print $2}'
```

and this:

```
awk -F" \\\|{3} " '{print $2}'
```

Comment: At least GNU awk allows for `awk -F" [|]{3} "`.

Comment: @martin For some strange reason the `{3}` seems to work on all `awk` I have tried, also some `busybox` version.  Normal with `gnu awk 3.xx` you need to add `--re-interval` as an option to `gnu awk` to make the `{3}` to work with regex, but for some reason this is not the case for `FS`

Answer (score 0):

Use Single quotation mark   '

```
echo 'field1 ||| field2 ||| field3' | awk -F'\\|\\|\\|' '{print $3}'
 field3
```